# Java Web - Método remove Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.lang.Integer

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Gent,e estou tentando criar um método no qual eu deleto o registro do banco de dados. Porém, está dando o seguinte erro:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.lang.Integer
```

Código:

```
public void  delete(int user)  {
    Consultar consulta = new Consultar ();


    EntityManager deletar = consulta.getEntityManager();

    System.out.println("usuário deletado"+user);

        deletar.getTransaction().begin();
        deletar.remove(user);
        deletar.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`user` é uma variável do tipo `int`.

`deletar` é o nome dado ao seu `EntityManager` (péssimo nome).

Quando você faz isso:

```
deletar.remove(user);
```

Você está pedindo ao `EntityManager` para remover um inteiro do banco de dados. Isso não tem sentido. Remover de onde? De qual tabela?

O objeto que você deveria passar para o método `remove` deveria ser do tipo `User`, `Usuário` ou alguma coisa que você tenha que possua a anotação `@Entity`.

Comment: fiz essa mudança mas não acontece nada.                                       
 public void  delete(Usuario user)  {
 Consultar consulta = new Consultar ();
 
 //Long primaryKey = Long.parseLong(user);

 
 EntityManager entity = consulta.getEntityManager();
 
 System.out.println("usuário deletado"+user);

  
 entity.getTransaction().begin();
 entity.remove(user);
 entity.getTransaction().commit();
}

Comment: no deletar.remove vc tem que inserir uma entidade e não o código dela, talvez vc possa usar o findById para encontrar a entidade e depois deleta-la